# Custom Post Type posts not being displayed for specified category id

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display all posts for a specific custom post type with a specific category. Right now, all posts from the specified post type are showing, but none show once I add a category id to the $args array. I am trying to get the Feature category to display, id shown in backend url is 3156. I currently have three posts in the Feature category (they are displaying correctly on the loop-category page).

```
               <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'technology_articles',
                        'cat' => 3156,
                        'posts_per_page' => -1
                    );
                    $my_query = null;
                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                ?>

                <?php if( $my_query->have_posts() ):?>
                    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div style="background: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');background-size:cover;background-position: center;">
                            <a class="featured--link" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                            <div class="slide-overlay">
                                <div class="category-tag">
                                    <a href="/technology_category/feature/">Feature</a>
                                </div>
                                <h2><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                <div class="posted">
                                    Posted on <?php the_time('M j, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php
                    endif;
                    wp_reset_query();
                ?>
```

[image: I am trying to get the Feature category to display, id shown in backend url is 3156.]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use tax_query. See below:

```
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'technology_articles',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'technology_category',
                        'terms' => 3156
                    )
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
```